# LWC navigation in Experience Cloud: redirect to login?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I've got a LWC running in an Experience Cloud page that is public (page 1).  When clicking a button, I want it to send users to another page (page 2), but that page is set to require login.  Current behavior using NavigationMixin is that if the user is logged in, it works, but if they're not logged in, clicking the button doesn't do anything at all.

As far as I can tell the LWC nav just refuses to go to page 2 because it's not accessible to the guest user.

Outside of the LWC context, If I'm not logged in and I attempt to go to the URL of page 2, I am automatically redirected to the login page.

Is there a way to get the LWC nav to do the same?  Auto redirect to login if user is not already logged in?  Or do I need to detect that in my code and do the redirect to login myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code snippets from the LWC that deal with the redirection (both client and server side code as necessary).